# XSLT template use inside a for-each cursor to map the last element

Tags: xslt

Following is the sample file that is have:
We need some help in the xslt transformation while using a position() in xslt

### Input:

```
 <ElementOne> 
 <RecordA>AAA</RecordA>
  </ElementOne>
<ElementOne>
 <RecordA>BBB</RecordA>
</ElementOne>
 <ElementOne> 
  <RecordA>CCC</RecordA>
</ElementOne>
<ElementTwo> 
  <DfiAccttNumber>123</DfiAccttNumber>
</ElementTwo>
 <ElementTwo> 
  <DfiAccttNumber>9999</DfiAccttNumber>
 </ElementTwo>
  <ElementTwo>
  <DfiAccttNumber>8889</DfiAccttNumber>
 </ElementTwo>
 <ElementTwo>
  <DfiAccttNumber>0000</DfiAccttNumber>
 </ElementTwo>
  <ElementTwo>
  <DfiAccttNumber>9696</DfiAccttNumber>
 </ElementTwo>
```

### XSD:

```
<xsd:element name="HeaderElement">
    <xsd:element name="ElementOne" nxsd:style="array" nxsd:cellSeparatedBy="${eol}" nxsd:conditionValue="1">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="RecordA" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="fixedLength" nxsd:length="2" />
           </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="ElementTwo" nxsd:style="array" nxsd:cellSeparatedBy="${eol}" nxsd:conditionValue="6">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="RecordB" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="fixedLength" nxsd:length="17" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
     </xsd:element>
```

### XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="cur"/>
<ebo:CreateReturnedItemListEBM>
  <DataArea>
    <xsl:for-each select="/imp1:HeaderElement/imp1:ElementTwo">
      <xsl:variable name="cur" select="position()"/>
      <ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
        <ebo:BankDetail>
           <ebo:AccountNumber>
            <ebo:Old>
              <xsl:value-of select="/imp1:HeaderElement/imp1:ElementTwo[$cur]/imp1:RecordB"/>
            </ebo:Old>
          </ebo:AccountNumber>
        </ebo:BankDetail>
        <ebo:Payment>
          <ebo:Bate>
        <xsl:value-of select="../imp1:ElementOne[$cur]/imp1:RecordA"/>
          </ebo:Bate>
        </ebo:Payment>
      </ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </DataArea>
</ebo:CreateReturnedItemListEBM>
```

### Response:

```
     <ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
     <ebo:BankDetail>
        <ebo:AccountNumber>
            <ebo:Old>123</ebo:Old>
         </ebo:AccountNumber>
      </ebo:BankDetail>
      <ebo:Payment>
        <ebo:Bate>AAA</ebo:Bate>
      </ebo:Payment>
   </ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
   <ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
     <ebo:BankDetail>
        <ebo:AccountNumber>
           <ebo:Old>9999</ebo:Old>
        </ebo:AccountNumber>
     </ebo:BankDetail>
     <ebo:Payment>
        <ebo:Bate>BBB</ebo:Bate>
     </ebo:Payment>
  </ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
  <ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
     <ebo:BankDetail>
        <ebo:AccountNumber>
           <ebo:Old>8889</ebo:Old>
        </ebo:AccountNumber>
     </ebo:BankDetail>
     <ebo:Payment>
        <ebo:Bate>CCC</ebo:Bate>
     </ebo:Payment>
  </ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
  <ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
     <ebo:BankDetail>
        <ebo:AccountNumber>
           <ebo:Old>0000</ebo:Old>
        </ebo:AccountNumber>
     </ebo:BankDetail>
     <ebo:Payment>
        <ebo:Bate/>
     </ebo:Payment>
  </ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
  <ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
     <ebo:BankDetail>
        <ebo:AccountNumber>
           <ebo:Old>9696</ebo:Old>
        </ebo:AccountNumber>
     </ebo:BankDetail>
     <ebo:Payment>
        <ebo:Bate/>  
     </ebo:Payment>
  </ebo:CreateReturnedItemList>
```

Here the Bate is getting empty because of the cusor is ended. I need to apply the last value of 'RecordA' to this Bate. If possible with a template

Comment: Your XSD, and XSLT, seems to suggest that **ElementTwo** nodes contain a child **RecordB** node, but there are no such nodes in your XML. Also, the XSLT is referencing a namespace prefix **imp1**, but there is no sign of namespaces in the XML (probably because you have forgotten to show the **HeaderElement**. Could you correct this please? Thank you.

Comment: As a quick and dirty answer, you could use this xpath expression instead of yours to output Bate :
if(../imp1:ElementOne[$cur]/imp1:RecordA) then (../imp1:ElementOne[$cur]/imp1:RecordA) else ../imp1:ElementOne[last()]/imp1:RecordA

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update the question with _at the very least_ the necessary code to replicate your issue: valid and well-formed XML, which is currently not true for any of your three code snippets. To help us help you, please also read the [ask].